# How to tell when text overflows p tag html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a simple webpage in which users can input text in an input area, and this will be added as a paragraph in a div element.  I have set up the p element's text-overflow property to be clip.  Is there any way I can tell if the text will be clipped, and if so, what text will be clipped?  Thank you all.

p.s. because of the specifications, I cannot change how the p handles overflow and I cannot add a scrollbar.  I need to design this exactly to the specs.

Comment: If your `p` tag has fixed with, maybe you can try to count how many characters can fit inside it and check the overflow via JS?

Comment: If the `p` does not have a specified width and height, the text will flow to fill the width of the page (or containing block) and then wrap onto two or more lines, thus, it will never overflow or clip.

Comment: You can use something like https://jsfiddle.net/o6br04q0/

Comment: You might actually want to let the users type in an invisible textarea, displaying what they type in a scalable element and measuring that. You can tie the focus and blur events to the other element to then capture the input and put it into the element.